# Is there a way to automatically update the value of a cell based on another cell, but only the first time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I'm looking to make a "Status" column in google sheets that updates automatically but can still be manually changed. Here is a simplified [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/124N_UR4GlHW-bMO3GmtL5jRSNhK21ciRYF4Tz1cpL5M/edit#gid=0) that shows the kind of thing I'm trying to do. Based on different criteria for each status, I want the status to automatically update once. For example, when a name is added under "Assigned Writer," I want the status for that row to automatically change to "Assigned." When today is past "Due Date" and there's nothing in "Submitted Date," I want the status to automatically change to "Draft Past Due."

The thing is, I want these changes to happen only once, so that rows can have their statuses manually updated or changed without interference. The actual sheet has a lot more statuses with different criteria, so I'm not so much concerned about writing that specific criteria (as long as there's somewhere in the script I can insert them reasonably easily) but more concerned about the part where it updates only the first time. Any thoughts?

Comment: I see seven unique statuses.  Could you build a table of actions that cause those status

Comment: Also are all the actions that lead to status changes originated from a user input?

Comment: Each cell in the sheet can be variably filled by user input, vlookups from other sheets, or automatic formulas from other cells. Basically I've tried my best to automate a lot of the process, but sometimes people don't follow protocols so we have to update information manually.

I've added a chart that describes when to trigger each status.

Comment: onEdit triggers are generated only by user edits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //Logger.log(gobj.globals.yoursheetname);
  if (sh.getName() == gobj.globals.yoursheetname && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let hs = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
    let col = {};
    hs.forEach((h, i) => { col[h] = i + 1 });
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(col));
    if(e.range.columnStart == col["Assigned Writer"] && e.value)e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue("Assigned");
    if(e.range.columnStart == col["Draft Submitted"] && e.value)e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue("In Review");
    if(e.range.columnStart == col["Draft Accepted"] && e.value)e.range.offset(0,-4).setValue("Accepted");
  }
}
```